# Bootstrap 3 form input element's size attribute does not change lenght of same

Tags: forms, input, size, twitter-bootstrap-3

With Bootstrap 3, form input element size does not change as specified by `size` attribute, code snippet:

```
<input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" type="email" size="50">
```

I understand that there are workarounds to shorten the length of an input element but, help me understand why doesn't it work with `size` attribute of `input` element?

Working code at [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/100368).

Thanks!

Comment: are you using bootstrap 3?

Comment: Oh yes. I missed to specify, updated OP after your pointer. Thanks for same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things you could do. You could use Bootstrap's `col-*` classes to change how your form lays out, or you can either modify the CSS or add inline styles to your inputs (such as `<input ... style="width:200px;">`).

I would personally try to use the `col-*` classes for consistency, even though it adds a bit more markup to your pages. As an example, something like this:

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="col-sm-4">Email address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" size="50" type="email">
    </div>
  </div>
...
```

I'd also try to follow the documentation and examples from [the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

Comment: I understand that there are workarounds to shorten the length of an input element but, help me understand why doesn't it work with 'size' attribute of 'input' element?

Comment: Because the CSS declaration in Bootstrap overrides the `size` attribute in most browsers.

Comment: Specifying width in 'em' is better that 'px'.

Comment: In most cases, yes. I was just giving a simple example for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using bootstrap 3 try placing your inputs in a div

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" type="email" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Visual Studio then you might want to **remove** Microsoft's defaults in the Site.css which contains:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```